# How do I hide IP addresses and credentials in config files on Github?

Tags: github, credentials, pgp

I want to use Github for some of my config files. These files have IP addresses and other sensitive information. I DO NOT want to .gitignore the entire file.

**How do I hide a single LINE or TEXT in the document?**

Is there an option to use PGP here or..?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://git-secret.io/ .  It might do exactly what you want.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. This is a cool tool and could be very useful. Unforunately, it seems that similar to .gitignore, git-secret deals with the entire file rather than individual values or lines on the code. I need to be able to keep (and share) config files with others (visually providing direction and guidance) without hiding the whole file.